# mysql sort order manipulation

Tags: mysql

I have a question related to a project I am currently working on.
In my script all posts are currently being displayed this way:

```
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts" 
      . "\n WHERE page_slug = '" . $this->slug . "'" 
      . "\n AND active = '1'" 
      . "\n ORDER BY id DESC" . $pg->limit;
      $result = $db->fetch_all($sql);
```

This is fine although the problem now is , that I want a certain item to be displayed first before all others. I tried to give this specific item a very high ID (e.g. 1000), although if I create a new post the new posts ID suddenly starts with 1001 and it jumps on first position.

Does anybody have an idea on how I can avoid this from happening or at least how I can "trick" a specific item to be at the first position by somehow tweaking the sort-order?

Some advise would be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much,
Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT *, case when id = 1000 then 0 else 1 end as OrderMe  FROM posts" 
  . "\n WHERE page_slug = '" . $this->slug . "'" 
  . "\n AND active = '1'" 
  . "\n ORDER BY OrderMe, id DESC" . $pg->limit;
  $result = $db->fetch_all($sql);
```

Of course you don't have to use 1000 as the id in the case statement, but you mentioned that was the id of the one you want on top...

Comment: Thank you - this seems to be a very interesting solution as well. Question: Is there a way to define multiple id's? E.g 1000, 1001 and 1002?

Comment: yup, have multiple when/then statements... eg `when id = 1000 then 0 when id=2002 then 1 else 2` OR use `in` eg `when id in (1000, 2002, 3054) then 0 else 1`

Comment: see [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) for more details of the case statement

Comment: Outstanding - when id in (...) works like charm ! What a great solution, thanks a lot appclay - I wish you have a great day ahead.

Answer (score 2):

You can `trick`, as you said, the DBMS this way:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE page_slug = @slug AND active = 1
ORDER BY (id != @yourID), id DESC, LIMIT @limit
```

The `@limit` and `@slug` are your current variables. The `@yourID` variable is the ID you want on top. If there are more than just one, use an `in()` clause. Basically, this will return `false`, or actually `0`, for the post which ID is equal to the one you're looking for, and `true`, or actually `1`, for the rest of the posts.

So, applying first and ascending order on that new generated value will result in the ones with `0` (the ones that are equal) on top :)

Comment: thanks - that sounds like a great solution ! Thank you Mosty Mostacho

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column called `rank` (or something else that's meaningful), assign it to some value above zero for rows which are more important.  You would then order by `rank` first, then order by `id`.

Comment: I've tried your solution as it seemed simple enough by using: . "\n ORDER BY rank, id DESC" . $pg->limit; but it does not seem to work

Comment: Try `ORDER BY rank DESC, id DESC`, all order by's are ascending unless specified otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not already some kind of module, turn that code into a module and don't duplicate it - it should be easy to change. Then, just add some `INT` field to the database (`priority`, for example) and `ORDER BY` priority, then by ID.